# How to slide it content in css

Tags: css, slide

How to implement animation push the right side container after click the slide button?

i try it with grid layout, seem grid is a block concept, if change to 1fr, it will expand immediately, cannot look like animation pushing....

below is my simple concept example.

```js
let slide = document.querySelector('.btn-push_right');
slide.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const gridTem = document.querySelector('.container');
  gridTem.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr"
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  border:2px solid blue;
  height:100vh;
}

.left{
  border:2px solid pink;
  height:100vh;
}
.btn-push_right{
  border:2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="btn-push_right">slide </span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>this area will be push away after click slide button</p>
  </div>
</div>
```